# How to make elements in one line JSF

Tags: jsf

How to make elements to render in one line like it is showed on image below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
                                <h:outputLabel
                                        value="&#160;#{cdocmsgs['promo.action.name']}&#160;"
                                        id="promo_action_name_id"/>

                                <h:selectOneMenu id="promotion" widgetVar="sub" tabindex="206"
                                                 styleClass="select-fix-average"
                                                 value="#{cdocBean.entity.promoActionName}" effect="fade"
                                                 required="#{cdocBean.entity.promotion}" requiredMessage="#{cdocmsgs['enter.promo']}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{cdocmsgs['promoSelect']}"
                                                  itemValue="" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{promoActionBean.DAO.resultList}"
                                                   var="item" itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.name}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                                <h:outputText value="" />


                                <h:outputLabel value="&#160;#{cdocmsgs['source.of.info']}&#160;"
                                               id="whenId"/>
                                <h:selectOneMenu id="source" widgetVar="sub"
                                                 styleClass="select-fix-average"
                                                 value="#{cdocBean.entity.source}" effect="fade" tabindex="206"
                                                 required="#{cdocBean.entity.promotion}" requiredMessage="#{cdocmsgs['enter.source']}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{cdocmsgs['sourceSelect']}"
                                                  itemValue="" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{adSourceBean.DAO.resultList}" var="item"
                                                   itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.name}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I have placed h:panelGroup but it did not help.

Comment: i don't know about jsf ... but it is not possible to do this with css?

Comment: Why not put these inside a html table coloumns

Comment: @Swarnajith because he is using JSF and the use of html table is discouraged- for styling purposes, DOM manipulation, lack of validations etc.

Comment: @jedrus07 all the jsf components render html tags so what you say is incorrect and i dont see any styling difficulties when doing that I have used this combination in many projects whenever i need. validations and all should be done with JSF you can use html tags inbetween them

Comment: @Swarnajith I agree with you in general, but if something is easily achievable by JSF- why not use JSF? Of course it renders into HTML, but if you have a powerful tool such as JSF, not using it seems wasteful. You lose all the benefits- from my experience they include ease of styling and Ajax manipulations if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use h:panelGrid like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" columnStyles="style1, style2, style3">    
    <jsfelement 1 />
    <jsfelement 2 />
    <jsfelement 3 />

    <jsfelement 4 />
    <jsfelement 5 />
    <jsfelement 6 />    
</h:panelGrid>
```

It will look like this:

element1 element2 element3

element4 element5 element6

And be rendered as a html table. You can of course style it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

use a simple html  would be one option.

or there are panelGrid and panelGroup in facelets to do that. usually the panlGroup is used inside the panelGrid to group multiple components into one cell.

an example: http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_panelGrid.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a html table

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td><h:outputLabel value="&#160;#{cdocmsgs['promo.action.name']}&#160;"
                                    id="promo_action_name_id"/></td>
    <td><h:selectOneMenu id="promotion" widgetVar="sub" tabindex="206"
                                             styleClass="select-fix-average"
                                             value="#{cdocBean.entity.promoActionName}" effect="fade"
                                             required="#{cdocBean.entity.promotion}" requiredMessage="#{cdocmsgs['enter.promo']}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{cdocmsgs['promoSelect']}"
                                              itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{promoActionBean.DAO.resultList}"
                                               var="item" itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.name}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu></td>
         <td><h:outputText value="" /></td>
         <td><h:outputText value="" /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```